# How can I get more spell slots for an ultimate magus without resorting to the feat Extra Slot?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, multi-classing, spells

I'm planning on a wizard/warmage/ultimate magus build. By level 15 the character'll have caster level 11 in both classes, yet 5 levels remain. I want to save the character's feats for metamagic feats, so I planned on the prestige class dragon disciple to get more spell slots without having to take the feat Extra Slot.

My problem is that dragon disciple focuses mainly on physical enhancements and doesn't advance spell casting. The natural armor bonus, +2 to Intelligence, and +2 Charisma are nice, but the character probably won't see that +2 Charisma until level 10, which puts the character into epic levels.

Is there a way besides dragon disciple or the feat Extra Slot to gain additional spell slots?

Comment: I know it's been a while, but does something prevent this character from gaining more slots the old-fashioned way: by taking additional wizard levels after finishing off ultimate magus?

Answer (score 15):

With an ultimate magus, it’s more important to keep yourself as close as possible to a single-classed spellcaster on one side than it is to keep the two even.

**Thus you want to circumvent as much as possible ultimate magus’s attempts to progress your lower-level class.**

Because at 1st, 4th, and 7th level, ultimate magus advances the class with lower caster level (your choice in the case of a tie), this has a tendency to even out your two classes. If you avoid that, and continue to progress in the more advanced class, you will have more of your highest-level spell slots, which are also higher level than they would be.

**Practiced Spellcaster is the solution to taking manual control over which class ultimate magus progresses.** Practiced Spellcaster increases a class’s caster level (but no other facet of its spellcasting) by up to 4 (capped at the spellcaster’s HD, so the feat is only beneficial to multiclassed spellcasters). Normally, caster level is nice but not *as* crucial as things like spell slots or higher spell levels. Ultimate magus switches this up, though.

If a Wizard 4/Sorcerer 1 takes Practiced Spellcaster for **sorcerer**, his weaker class, his sorcerer caster level is 5th. This puts it higher than his wizard spellcasting’s 4th caster level, so first level of ultimate magus advances wizard. This is despite the fact that the ultimate magus’s wizard spellcasting is, for most purposes, more advanced than his sorcerer spellcasting.

Now you have some control over your advancement, and that allows you to maximize your spell slots.

At 4th level, both classes are even, so you should choose wizard. At 7th, barring finding some other bonus to sorcerer caster level, though, you have to accept some sorcerer progression, which is a shame but not the end of the world. You’ll end up “missing” a total of two wizard spellcasting levels (compared to a single-classed wizard), but gain a total of nine sorcerer levels, plus of course all the rest of the ultimate magus class features.

Otherwise, you need to improve the abilities that grant you bonus spells. Consider the beguiler (*Player's Handbook II*) instead of sorcerer: you'll use Intelligence for both classes.

Versatile Spellcaster is another feat that will make your slots more flexible.

And *pearls of power* and *rings of wizardry* can help by letting you reuse slots. *Memento magicka* are like *pearls of power* for spontaneous spellcasters but they are 50% more expensive, which is badly overpriced.

Comment: Practiced Spellcaster does not affect spells known or spell slots. http://dndtools.eu/feats/complete-arcane--55/practiced-spellcaster--2231/

Comment: @LitheOhm: No, no it does not. What it does affect is which of your two classes Ultimate Magus advances, and Ultimate Magus advancement *does* improve spells known and spell slots. Basically, Ultimate Magus advances the class with the lower Caster Level. If you take Practiced Spellcaster in Sorcerer, it has a higher Caster Level than Wizard, even though your Wizard spellcasting is otherwise more advanced.

Comment: Ah, right. My bad :) haven't seen that class in a while.

Comment: If my understanding of Ultimate Magus is correct, on the levels where you can only advance one of your two spellcaster levels, you *have* to put them into the class with the fewest levels.

Comment: @Cobalt Yes, specifically and explicitly the one with the lowest **Caster Level**. But Practiced Spellcaster (sorcerer) gives you a bonus to your sorcerer Caster Level, pushing it above your wizard Caster Level even though your wizard spellcasting is otherwised more advanced than your sorcerer spellcasting. I'd call it cheesy if I wasn't busy calling the default stupid.

Comment: I thought that bonus applied to both of your classes.

Comment: The Ultimate Magus feature to boost Caster Level applies to both. The Practiced Spellcaster feat, however, applies to one class of your choice.

Comment: I think there is a slight issue here: a Wizard 3/Sorcerer 1, thus a level 4 character, should not be able to meet the "Spellcraft 8" requirement of the Ultimate Magus, should it? Thus I think the character should be level 5 before it veers into Ultimate Magus (at level 6), and since Practiced Spellcaster only covers the difference so far, it should be a Wizard 3/Sorcerer 2 or a Wizard 3/Sorcerer 1/Whatever 1 (the former probably being preferable). Am I off-track?

Comment: @MatthieuM. Hmm, that does seem to be an issue. I could have sworn there was a simple way to get this to work, I'll look into it. But even if there isn't, Wizard 4/Sorcerer 1 is best because you delay the second missed wizard level until 12th.

Comment: And if you want some cheese to go with your CL manipulation, you can always don and doff practiced spellcaster with [DCFS](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/70172/when-where-and-with-whom-did-the-dark-chaos-feat-shuffle-originate) at the cost of 500xp each swap.

Answer (score 9):

Having a few [Pearl of Power](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items/wondrous-items/wondrous-items/m-p/pearl-of-power) would enable you to cast more spells per day, and drastically increases your staying power for not a lot of cash. Wands are also a good cost effective way to increase your spell-casters' spells-per-day/encounter output.

Answer (score 7):

A *Ring of Wizardry* (DMG p233) will double the wearers arcane spells per day for one specific spell level (doesn't double bonus spells due to high ability scores or school specializations).

Answer (score 0):

## Pay tribute to Demons

According to Fiendish Codex, you can perform a Faustian Pact, that has a demand to sacrifice a percantage of your current wealth to Demons.

An additional slot(of any level, to which you have access) is a Reward with Rating 3 and it will require 20% of your current wealth.

For further information, read pages 23-25 from Fiendish Codex II.