# Is there any way to increase the number of spells I can cast per day as a wizard?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, wizard

I know about the bonus spells per day you get from your INT modifier and the specializing bonus. Is there any other way to get more spell casts per day?

Just to make sure I have this right, as a level 5 wizard with 16 int I can cast 2 3rd level spells per day. 1 from base and 1 from the bonus from my INT. If I specialize into evocation, I can cast 3 fireballs per day but only 2 non-evocation spells per day. If this is wrong in any way please let me know.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I get more spell slots for my caster without resorting to the Extra Slot feat?](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/18333/how-can-i-get-more-spell-slots-for-my-caster-without-resorting-to-the-extra-slot)

Comment: @Miniman Not really; in that case the most effective approach took advantage of the particular prestige class that he was using, which isn't the case here.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You really want to start with 18 Int, and by 5th level you should probably have a *headband of intellect +2*, for a total of 20 Int. Won’t help your 3rd-level spells, but it will give you another 1st-level spell and it will also help your save DCs; any spell that someone fails a save to that they otherwise would have made, is a spell you don’t have to cast again.

Smart use of your spell slots also goes a *very* long way. If you hit some dudes with a *fireball*, they take some damage. They probably aren’t dead, though, and you’ll probably end up having to hit them with another *fireball*. And in the meantime, they are just as dangerous to your allies as they were before, and your allies are no more effective than they were.

If, instead, you *haste* your allies, you double the damage the fighter or barbarian and cleric or druid do, you give a dual-wielding rogue another attack (and, hopefully, that means another Sneak Attack), and so on. This will add up to a lot more damage than a *fireball*, you don’t have to worry about aiming, and if the first set of *hasted* attacks isn’t sufficient to kill them all, your allies remain *hasted* for several rounds without you having to cast another spell.

Alternatively, [*grease*](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/17191/4563) and *glitterdust* are some phenomenally effective debuffs: *grease* can have enemies flat on their back, or refusing to move for fear of falling, and really lets a rogue go to town, while *glitterdust* blinds which, for most things at low level, means they’re basically incapable of performing as any kind of threat. Best of all, these are a 1st-level and 2nd-level spell, respectively: you can save your higher-level spell slots for *fly*, perhaps, for scouting or just keeping yourself out of danger.

Ultimately, these are how a wizard is powerful, not through direct-damage. Most direct-damage spells are weak. Consequently, Evocation as a school is fairly weak (and its best spells, *contingency* and *resilient sphere*, are some of the few evocations that don’t deal damage). Specialization is a very good idea, but often because it’s no big loss to ban Evocation (and Enchantment); see [here](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/19558/4563) for all about specializing and the best ways to do it. You’ll notice that the four spells I recommend are all Conjuration (*grease* and *glitterdust*) or Transmutation (*haste* and *fly*); that’s not a coincidence. Specializing in these very diverse schools is an excellent way to extend your day, both by giving you another spell, and also by simply having each spell count for more.

Finally, it’s worth noting that pretty soon, your basic spells per day, specialized or not, are going to get pretty large. Pretty soon, if you spend your spell slots wisely, it will be a rare day when you are actually risking running out. For now, it’s a real concern, but you can get by. If you want, though, *pearls of power* are the way to expand your spells per day.

Comment: How "should" a level 5 Wizard have a headband of intellect?

Comment: @Behacad A 5th-level character should have 9,000 gp in wealth, 3,400 of which was gained in the last level. A _headband of intellect +2_ costs 4,000 gp, and is just about a wizard’s _only_ priority. It still leaves enough money to get a _cloak of resistance +1_ and a _+1 mithral buckler_, which would really be the only other major considerations at that level. So there is every reason to have one, and no good reason not to.

Comment: Can one just walk into a store and buy those things? I guess my DM has been screwing us! haha. I was under the impression that magic item superstores weren't really a thing.

Comment: @Behacad It depends massively on the gameworld, but ultimately a wizard should have *some way* of gaining that item. Custom order, a sidequest, crafting it himself, perhaps. But whatever it is, Pathfinder characters are massively dependent on magic items—and not just the concept of an item that is magic, but literally of *having specific, select magic items crucial to their class*. Wizards actually can survive reasonably well without a *headband of intellect*, as the wizard class is massively overpowered anyway, but fighters and others absolutely must have their items.

Answer (score 8):

[Pearls of Power](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items/wondrous-items/wondrous-items/m-p/pearl-of-power) are the main way to get more spells per day, but that gets expensive.

Plus, of course, crafting scrolls or wands lets you cast spells using them without using a spell slot. (Which can get very expensive fast)

Other than that, there really isn't any other way I know of.

The limited spells per day is the major balancing factor of wizards; if they could cast without worrying about running out of spells, there'd be no stopping them.

Answer (score 5):

There are not many ways to get more spell slots per day save by being a specialist wizard or increasing your Int score, and they usually aren't worth the effort.

The Spellcasting Prodigy feat lets you fake a slightly higher Int score for the purpose of determining your bonus spell slots.
The Extra Slot feat gains you an extra slot of a given level.

As far as items go, *Pearls of Power* allow you to get back a spell you already cast, and a Circlet of the Magi (SpC) allows you not to spend the spells. Rings of Wizardry I-IV double the base spell slots of a single spell level, while a good selection of scrolls, wands, eternal wands (SpC) and minor schema (ECS, if I recall correctly) allow you to cast spells without spending your spell slots.

Comment: Nice list; also Mnemonic Enhancer if used well at higher levels.

Answer (score 5):

Ring of Wizardry 1-4 are pretty decent items, depending on what you want to do.

RoW3 is by far the best, because level 3 spells are great even up to high levels, and level 3 is the highest level that works with lesser metamagic rods. When you get to higher levels and find you don't have time in your combats to cast level 3 spells, buy lesser rods of quicken and go nuts with haste/throw out random fireballs for pretty much no cost.

Depending on how many casters are in your group, you may also find some value in a RoW 1 at high levels. Some paranoid groups use 'Detect magic' pretty much constantly to detect magic traps, and detect people that might be shapechanged/dominated etc, to find loot, or even just to tell if there are any other NPCs nearby (by high level, all NPCs worth worrying about will have magic)

Answer (score 1):

**Node Store** gives you two extra spell slots for spells that can be stored in a node (and to which you will only have access while within the area of that node).  You have to choose what two spells you can use with the feat from amongst the spells you know when you take the feat.  So, really only useful to a mage who either is on his home ground or ground he has scouted out for a node and set up a base of operations there.  (Anyone going this route should also consider picking up **Sanctum Spell**.)

[It doesn't specify if the two slots have to be applied one each to each spell chosen or if you can, on any given day, choose to use both slots for just one of the spells.  It does, however, say that if you take the feat again it applies to two new spells, so even if the slots are mix-n-match within a feat, it doesn't look like they would be between copies of the feat.]

**Familiar Spell** works similarly, but in this case the spell is stored in the mind of your familiar and has to be a spell that you have mastered via **Spell Mastery**.  Rather than having to be within the area of a node to access the spell, you need your familiar to be within 5'.  Like **Node Store**, this feat can be taken multiple times, with each time giving another slot that is stored in your familiar.

[While my initial reaction to this feat was "You only get one slot, so why would you take this instead of just taking **Extra Slot** in the first place, which doesn't require **Spell Mastery** or a nearby familiar?"  Upon further reflection, I realized that **Extra Slot** locks you into whatever level spell slot you select when you take the feat, but every time you take **Spell Mastery** would add new choices to **Familiar Spell**, so a high-Int wizard with multiple copies of each feat would potentially have an extensive selection.  Still don't know if it would be worth it, but that would be a decision each player would have to make for their own character.]

**Arcane Manipulation** allows a wizard to break his spells slots down into any number of lower level slots, so long as the total spell levels of the new slots equals the level of the slot used to create them.  (Zero level spells count as half a level for this purpose.)  You can break down up to three spells slots in this manner.  [This one does *not* say anything about being able to take it multiple times, so that three slots broken down is all you'll ever be able to get with it.]

**Versatile Spellcaster** can accomplish the nearly the opposite for spontaneous casters, though not quite as efficiently.  In this case, it takes two slots of an identical level to cast a spell one level higher than those slots, so it results in a net loss of total spell slots, but if what matters is the ability to increase slots for a particular level (or to take advantage of the many slots of the level the caster has a *ring of wizardry* for) then it might be worth considering.

[No limit is place on how many of their spell slots a caster may do this with, so a mage who, via a *hand of glory*, is wearing three *rings of wizardry*, might get up to considerable shenanigans with this feat.  If, for example, the caster had *rings* for 1st, 3rd, and 5th level, he could use some of those extra slots for those levels and, via **Versatile Spellcaster**, use others to increase how many 2nd, 4th, and 6th level spells he casts that day, depending on his needs.]