# What is the best "core" race for DCFS abuse?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, feats, optimization, races

Some races grant racial feats as bonuses. These could be [DCFS'd](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/70172/3548) into any other feat of interest to the character.

Limiting the scope to the races in the 3.5 PHB what is the race with the most bonus feats to use with the DCFS?

Comment: Did you do *any* research on this question before asking us? There are literally only seven races to even *consider* from that set of books, and those are all core because PHB2 doesn’t even have any races.

Answer (score 5):

## Elf: 4 feats

Elf gains the Martial Weapon Proficiency feat **four** times.

Human gains a **single** feat, that you get to choose anyway.

No other *Player’s Handbook* race gains any feats that you can use.

*Player’s Handbook II* doesn’t include any races at all.

Comment: Do the weapon proficiencies that elves gain count as feats? I seem to recall it just says they gain proficiency, with no mention of feats. Of course, it's been ages since I looked at the 3.5 PHB, and my memory is iffy, so...

Comment: @ObliviousSage "Elves receive the Martial Weapon Proficiency feats for the longsword, rapier, longbow (including composite longbow), and shortbow (including composite shortbow) as bonus feats" (*PH* 16).

Comment: @HeyICanChan Ah, OK, I must have been remembering a newer version.

Comment: @heyicanchan "class" slipped in as a typo. its race.

Comment: @ObliviousSage: It's probably because most other races, even when they get proficiencies, do not explicitly gain the feat, they just are proficient (or *familiar*).